# 'greater that' instead of 'greater than' - typo, autocorrect or new usage?

Tags: grammaticality, that, typographical-errors

I regularly see people on the web type things like 'The health benefits of cycling are **greater that** the risks of being sedentary', where to me that should be 'greater **than**'.

It seems like an odd typo for so many people to make, as on a QWERTY keyboard or even the old style mobile predictive text the T and N aren't really close enough to be an accidental button press.

'Greater than' is obviously a valid phrase so is it just being autocorrected to that even though it's the incorrect usage for the context?

Or is this a new usage that will become ingrained more and more as people see it more often?

Some examples can be found here, but I must see it multiple times a day in the web forums I read: https://www.google.com/search?safe=active&q=%22greater+that%22+vs+%22greater+than%22&nfpr=1&sa=X

Comment: If these are tweets or Internet comments I am still likely to blame auto correct. The more frequently used word will sometimes substitute the less common automatically and silently. The author misses it and posts an ungrammatical phrase.

Comment: Surely '0.987 is greater than 0.9 because if you expand up to equivalent decimal ... Hence here 0.987 being the larger quantity has to be greater that 0.9' virtually proves an error of some sort. What sort is not a matter for ELU.

Comment: From my own personal experience, Some software program on my smartphone routinely spells my words for me as I compose a text. It's as though the program anticipates what I'm going to write, or it doesn't "think" the word I really want to use is the appropriate word, so it provides the word it thinks ought to be there! Glitch in the program, I say. Even after I correct the correction, sometimes the program simply prevents me from spelling the word the way I want it to be spelled! Crazy! Don

Comment: From you first example: "Which number you see greater that is the greater number", I think is meant to be parsed, "Which number you see greater, that is the greater number", not "greater that".

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think it is due to a misreading of some examples, not a trend or new usage pattern.